# "You don't know what you're getting" - why is present continuous used here?

Tags: verbs, present-tense, present-continuous

> This bundle pack contains ten 7-inches from K Artists and our Friends & Neighbors. Its contents were randomly selected by Calvin Johnson and span decades of underground music.
>
> It's a mystery wrapped in a cardboard enigma! You don't know what **you're getting**. Neither do we. But we guarantee it'll be great!

"You are getting" is future in that case. Present continuous is used because it is an arrangement or it has been planned. But what I don't understand is that the action of buying  has not been planned necessarily  before  or shall I understand that if you accept to buy it, an arrangement is created and present continuous is justified?

Comment: It is not really a future but a statement of a general truth about the bundle pack.  When one places an order for such a pack, its contents are not known in advance.  It **is** a mystery.

Comment: but if it is a general truth  we shall use present simple so why present continuous

Comment: The simple present would be valid there, but the continuous casts the acquisition as an unfolding event, one that is not confined to an instant in time.  *Touch this wire and you get a shock.*  *He is getting a haircut*.

Comment: that is not confined to an instant in time and  gives it to the event a higher importance than if the author will have used present simple . But I tought that using continuous tense was less formal than present simple

Comment: I would use the phrase **heightened drama** not **higher importance**, and it is simply the case that formal documents typically don't cast events as events taking place but as events in the abstract.  The continuous is not "informal".

Answer (score 1):

We can use the present continuous to refer to an act in progress.

> What are you doing at the computer?  It's time to go!
>   --I'll be there in a minute. I'm getting a T-shirt on eBay.

We can use the present continuous to refer to something you intend to be doing:

> That's it, I'm getting a new phone! The screen on this one just went blank again.

The continuous casts the action as one taking place in time, rather than one that happens in an instant.

The continuous can be used to express general truths about things that take place over time, things that are not confined to an instant in time:

> When you're on LSD, you're tripping.
>
> When you're "eating crow", you're having to admit you were wrong after insisting you were right.
>
> If you're "singing the blues", you're complaining about something.